# Trying to hide a H3 on jQuery with a somewhat complex css structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

At the moment i'm working on a site on wordpress and i've stumbled upon a problem.

I'm trying to hide a Heading 3 that's in a div. Though it's from a 960gs structure so the problem is that I need to hide that specific H3 on that page although I have multiple divs with the same name+heading 3's.

Now what I tried on my css is this:

CSS:

```
<div class="item col_2">
    <div class="phone">
        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image[2]; ?> " alt="<?php echo $alt_img; ?> "/>
        <?php //echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.item col_2 .phone:empty').closest('.item col_12 h3').remove();
```

Screenshot:

[image]

So what I tried to do was remove the heading "mobiel" whenever the "php inside" wouldn't fetch images in other words if noone uploaded anything.

Now my jquery isn't working but i'm pretty sure when it does it'll hide all h3's on my site with .col_12 h3 inside of it? If it does and there's no solution then i'll just blatantly paste it on the same page but first I'll need to fix my jQuery so it'll work at all.

Comment: Can you try something like that? I'm not sure whether i really understood the question. $('.item col_2 .phone:empty').closest('.item col_12').find( h3').remove();

Comment: I'm not sure about your selector. `.item col_2` isn't it looking for a class `item` and an HTML element `col_2` in this construction?
Not sure how jquery selector works when asigning multiple classes to one element.

Comment: You are right a point is missing. $('.item .col_2 .phone:empty').closest('.item .col_12').find( h3').remove();

Comment: Well we have 2 divs and one of the divs sometimes is empty and i'm trying to hide the H3 IF that one div is empty. And yes that was my bad @user3008011 just noticed it but it still didn't work..

Comment: All my answers are wrong... the right one is what Slavenko Miljic said! sorry!!!

Comment: It unfortunately still isn't working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble re-creating your problem, so I made a fiddle.
The problem is with the `:empty` selector I think. This seems to be a rather shady selector.
I replaced it with a check for `html().length`

Code

```
$('.item.col_2 .phone').each(function(){    
if( !$.trim( $(this).html() ).length ){
    $(this).parent().prev().find('h3').remove();
}
});
```

Check my fiddle for an example
http://jsfiddle.net/Esn2j/

For empty in stead of remove change `remove()` to `emtpy()`. Like so

```
$('.item.col_2 .phone').each(function(){    
if( !$.trim( $(this).html() ).length ){
    $(this).parent().prev().find('h3').empty();
}
});
```

UPDATE:

To check if the source of the image is empty, use the following code:

```
$('.item.col_2 .phone').each(function(){    
if($(this).find("img").attr("src") == ""){
    $(this).parent().prev().find('h3').empty();
}
```

});

Check my updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Esn2j/2/

Anthony's suggestion to use the clearfix as selector:

```
$('.clearfix').prev().find("h3").empty();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Esn2j/3/

This works for every H3 that is in a div before a clearfix however.

UPDATE:
This checks all the elements if the div with class thumbs is inside or not, by checking your code, I think this is created when the image exists. If the div with class thumbs is not inside, the H3 gets emptied.

```
$(".item.col_12").not(':has(.thumbs)').each(function(){
    $(this).find("h3").empty();
});
```

Check the new fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Esn2j/4/

ANSWER:
The code that generates the images is wrapped inside a div with the class `.confirm`

The  following code checks if that div exists on the page, if it exists, checks if it is empty or not, of it is empty, H3 tags are emptied.

```
if($(".confirm").length >0 ){
    if( !$.trim( $(".confirm").html() ).length ){
        $(".item.col_12").find("h3").empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: That was almost right. What I ment was that h3 needs to become empty whenever there is nothing in .phone

Comment: All you need to do for that is change remove() to empty() =). I'll update the code

Comment: According to Slavenko the codes won't work because there is `img` inside .phone so wether it's empty or not it won't work?

Comment: Wait? I thought you wanted to empty the H3 when there was NO image inside the .phone div?
What is the exact content of .phone when you want to empty H3?

Comment: I by the way tried the updated code and it still won't work..maybe it really is because `img` is in it?

Comment: NO image due to php, not a src of some sort. So i'm guessing that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, as the code is written in my example, it will empty the H3 when there is absolutely no code inside .phone

Comment: @user3121076 Check the source of the page for the elements you think should match and post the HTML here.

Comment: Ah, so you want to check if the image's source is empty? I can work with that, give me a sec =)

Comment: @user3121076 Check my updated answer, should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist `<div class="item col_12">
   <h3>Phone</h3>
  </div>` Is what you will see because PHP doesn't show anything anyway if nothing is uploaded in the backend(cms). BUT on other pages IF something is uploaded you see this: `<div class="item col_2"><div class="phone"><img src="http://pms72.shared01.ws01.webscale.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/IMG_0140-220x293.png" width="220" height="293 " alt="IMG_0140 "></div></div>` Now what needs to happen is IF the phone class is empty(`img` only appears if something is uploaded so it's not `<img></img>` the `h3` needs to become empty as well.

Comment: @user3008011 I hope I explained it perfectly this time, i'm sorry for the trouble. `img` nor `src` is there if nothing is uploaded.

Comment: @user3121076 I'm confused. Your first example (nothing uploaded) doesn't even *have* a `.phone` element... I/We need to see the whole thing: header and the (supposedly empty) container where the `<img>` *would* go if there was one. Edit the HTML into the question, formatting in comments is awful.

Comment: @user3121076
If the `.phone` elemen is completely empty(check source), my second piece of could should work.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @user3008011 So if it doesn't work it means it's not completely empty? While in the inspect element on my browser it shows it's empty? o.O And if so jquery can't do something like this because it's not empty?

Comment: @user3121076 We need to see the full HTML that you get for a post (or whatever it is) that doesn't have an `<img>`. You just posted `<div class="item col_12"> <h3>Phone</h3> </div>` before, but based on everything you've said so far there's a second part where the image would live. *That's what we need to see*.

Comment: @user3121076 If you check your source and the element is completely empty and it is still not working, that could mean either two things. Your Jquery is not included correctly, or your actual HTML structure is different from what you provided in your original question.

Comment: Wait I think I know what's going on, I think this is a Wordpress related issue. What happens on wordpress is that you script on ONE file for MULTIPLE pages. So what happens is that you add that code for ex. and on one page it's filled with an img and on another it's not and therefore conflicts with itself?

Comment: I pasted exactly what's there but I can provide a screenshot and I as well updated the post with a link, You should navigate to "volgende" to see a page on which there ARE images on "mobiel" or "tablet"

Comment: Screenshot might help out defining the actual structure, also check that the jquery is actually live on the page, see if you can find it in your source, I don't know how you are inserting it.

Also, if you have firebug, see if it returns any errors.

Comment: @user3121076 Screenshot would work, or just dump the entire HTML source for the page you're having issues with into something like pastebin.

Comment: I did test it earlier to confirm if it gets `.page` or `h3` without adding `.item.col_2` and it worked (Back with slavenko)

Comment: @user3121076 So the Tablet or Mobiel headers are the issue? The elements after them look nothing like what you've posted...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist But they are exactly that(In the backend) that's why I wrote "some php code" because PHP won't show on the page source anyway!

Comment: @user3121076 What I'm seeing in Firebug is `<div class="item col_12"><h3>Tablet</h3></div><div class="clearfix"></div>`. Nothing about an element with a `phone` class on it there.

Comment: There are two divs though `.phone` and `.tablet` does that mean they aren't there at all although they do show in my screenshot??

Comment: So the element is not empty, it's non existant.

Comment: Holy crap! I'm soooo stupid it of course gets created IF anything exists. I am sooooooo stupid! So that means all we have is `col_12 with h3`?

Comment: So the jquery needs to be changed to "if exists" or something in that sense?

Comment: @user3121076 You have the `<div class="clearfix"></div>` element directly after it, you could probably use that to identify them. It may cause issues with other parts of your page, not sure. Give this a try: `$('div.clearfix').prev('div.item.col_12 h3').remove();`

Comment: Well according to the live source, yes, that is all we have. =)
So let's rephrase the question because I'm not exactly sure what you want anymore.

You want to empty the H3 in col_12, but when do you want this to happen?

Comment: Hmm that didn't work at all but all in all clearfix is empty too so all it does is add a few css elements and it's on the entire website at parts so I guess that wouldn't be to smart to do. Isn't there a jquery function to check if something exists and if it doesn't it'd need to empty/remove the h3? It has to happen if `.item.col_2 .phone` exists.

Comment: Shouldn't it happen if `.item.col_2 .phone` does NOT exist?

Comment: Whoa i'm confusing myself. Yes if `.item.col_2 .phone` does NOT exist `h3` has to become empty.

Comment: @user3121076

Allright, check my lates update in the answer.

`$(".item.col_12").not(':has(.thumbs)').each(function(){
    $(this).find("h3").empty();
});
`

Should work for you

Comment: It did remove the Headings yes that's great! Although it also removed the headings on the pages where there ARE `img src`'s what exactly does `.thumbs` do or what is it? Looks to me like a class?

Comment: It is a class. It generated that class in your example. You could try replacing `.thumbs` with `img` but I don't think `:has` checks for child elements

Comment: Hmm `img` didn't work as well but could you specifically tell me where `.thumbs` came from? I don't see it in the inspect element on both pages o.o.

Comment: Nevermind I found it that's from the huge image above and so I get what you mean. What I did was change `.thumbs` into `.phone` because that's I guess what we're trying to fetch and if it's not there it would remove `h3` right? But appearently that didn't help... I as well tried to change `col_12` into `col_2` and that as well didn't help. Is it maybe better if I create another div that will ALWAYS be there around where `.phone` would've been and check if that's empty?

Comment: Could you maybe reverse the code because this is what I have at the moment, I added a div around `phone` which COULD be non existant but the div added ALWAYS exists named `confirm`. `$(".confirm").not(':has(.phone)').each(function(){
    $(this).find("h3").empty();
});` I have the feeling this code needs to be reversed, is that true and if so could you do that please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46331/discussion-between-user3121076-and-user3008011)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.item.col_2 .phone:empty').parent().prev().find('h3').remove();
```

Basically, if div is empty, go to its parent(`.item.col_2`), then go one element up(`.item.col_12`) and find `h3` inside that element

The `closest()` function that you used is searching the closest parent in the hierarchy tree.

You could use

`$('.phone:empty').parent().prev().find('h3').remove();`

to target all the .phone divs and then traverse through the elements

Not sure how are you inserting your data into .phone div but I believe that if you have whitespaces or newline spaces inside it the jQuery :empty will return false.

**[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Nf9/1/)**

EDIT:

Why don't you use PHP to check if the $content is empty end then print appropriate divs?

Comment: Missing a dot `.item.col_2`

Comment: But doesn't parent mean that "h3" has to be inside "col_2"? Because it's not working and I thought that was the reason( I have col_12 and col_2)

Comment: The parent means only the parent of the selector that you're targeting. You could do something like `$('.phone:empty').parent().prev().find('h3').remove();` to target all empty `.phone` divs

Comment: Hmm I understand now. Yet it doesn't want to hide the heading although I completely understand what you mean. Is there a way to test that line of script, for mistakes and such? For ex. if it actually finds 'h3' (I'm not to good with jquery)

Comment: Slavenko, I tested h3 and phone and it can catch both with a "hello world" ontop of them and it seems that .parent etc could be the issue here?

Comment: @user3121076 You're putting spaces between classes on the same element, that's incorrect. The space indicates that the next part of the selector is an element **inside** the ones matched by the previous part. So `.item .col_12 .phone` is a `.phone` element inside a `.col_12` element inside a `.item` element. You want a `.phone` element inside an element with both of the classes `item` and `col_12`, so no space: `.item.col_12 .phone`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thank you for that stupid mistake! But it still isn't working though I confirmed with a test that H3 and .phone are both being found by jquery so the mistake must be in the code itself..

Comment: @SlavenkoMiljic I updated it i'm not sure what exactly you mean with "whitespaces" wether it's a spacebar after <?php echo or whatever it could be but I updated my post please have a look!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of 'space' character. Basically the selector will work only if the '.phone' div is completely empty but now i see that in your updated question you have `img` inside the div, and the code above won't work

Comment: How could I solve this then? Thanks for all the effort by the way.(stupid wordpress issues) By the way @SlavenkoMiljic on inspect element you don't see `img` in it

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to check if the $content is empty end then print appropriate divs?